# How to add ComboBox to settings gear menu in Rally app

Tags: javascript, combobox, settings, rally

Currently I'm working on an app that displays a chart of defects.  The chart is to be filtered by a selection of checkboxes that the user can change around to fit his / her needs.  These checkboxes are located in the gear menu of the app, under 'settings'.  In App.js I have a function that looks like this:

```
getSettingsFields: function() {
    return [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: 'States',
            defaultType: 'checkboxfield',
            items: [
                {...}
                ...
            ]
        }
    ];
}
```

This function works perfectly so far and displays the items I left out of the code [they're not important to the question].  The problem is that now I want to add a ComboBox into the same settings page with custom values.  The box should have the text [Days, Weeks, Months, Quarters] inside that will further filter which defects to display in the chart.  I tried changing the getSettingsFields function to the following:

```
getSettingsFields: function() {
    var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['value', 'range'],
        data: [
            {'value':'day', 'range':'Days'}, //test data for ComboBox
            {'value':'week', 'range':'Weeks'}
        ]
    });

    return [
        {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Date Range',
            store: myStore,
            displayField: 'range',
            valueField: 'value'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: 'States',
            defaultType: 'checkboxfield',
            items: [
                {...}
                ...
            ]
        }
    ];
}
```

Now when I run the app and click on the 'settings' button, everything disappears - even the field of checkboxes.  Any explanation to why this is not working would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically doing everything correctly- you've just stumbled upon a really subtle bug.  The underlying issue is that there is an infinite recursion that occurs when the settings panel is attempting to clone the settings field config array due to the inclusion of the store.  The following code will work around the issue:

```
{
    xtype: 'rallycombobox',
    storeConfig: {
        fields: ['value', 'range'],
        data: [
            {'value':'day', 'range':'Days'}, //test data for ComboBox
            {'value':'week', 'range':'Weeks'}
        ]
    },
    storeType: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fieldLabel: 'Date Range',
    displayField: 'range',
    valueField: 'value'
}
```

It's basically the same as what you had but uses the rallycombobox instead and passes in storeType and storeConfig to get around the store cloning problem.

Comment: Also, this bug is fixed in the upcoming 2.0 GA release of the App SDK.