# Rally 2.0RC3 - Retrieving last saved setting in RallyCombobox with custom values

Tags: rally

I currently use a setting with a RallyCombobox. It appears in the settings screen fine, and passes the user's chose back to the app fine too. But the settings screen does not load the persisted value into the rallycombobox. It always displays the first item when the screen is opened (default behavior).

Another similar question ([How to add ComboBox to settings gear menu in Rally app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686269/how-to-add-combobox-to-settings-gear-menu-in-rally-app)) got me to this point, but need help with this last issue.

```
getSettingsFields: function() {

    return [
        {
            xtype: 'rallycombobox',
            name: 'selectedcolumns',
            storeConfig: {
                fields: ['dataIndex', 'text'],
                data: [
                    { text: 'Display1', dataIndex: 'id1' },
                    { text: 'Display2', dataIndex: 'id2' },
                    { text: 'Display3', dataIndex: 'id3' }
                ]
            },
            multiSelect: true,
            storeType: 'Ext.data.Store',
            fieldLabel: 'Columns:',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'dataIndex'
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: anyone? I feel this should have been easy to do.